# Numpy Array Local variable reference Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, numpy

I'm getting an error with `npArray` however `listvals` works just fine. How would I be able to fix it so that the numpy array works just like `listvals`?

Code:

```
import numpy as np

listvals=[]
npArray=np.array([])

def Run():
    for n in range(5):
        listvals.append(n)
        npArray = np.append(npArray, n)  
Run()
```

Error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'npArray' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Because of the assignment, `npArray` is a local variable.  It can't use the array with the same name outside the function.  That's a basic Python function issue.  This would work with a `list.append` which modifies the list in-place.  More generally wrapping something like this in a function, without passing the list/array as argument is not a good idea.  And repeated use of `np.append` in a loop is also not a good idea.

Comment: So how would I be able to fix it just pass the array through the function? Hwy is it not a good idea if I may ask?

Comment: Is this just a learning exercise, or are you intentionally trying to rewrite a list loop with numpy?  `list.append` operates in-place and is relatively fast.  `np.append` is a badly named cover to `np.concatenate` (see its code), and is inefficient when used repeatedly.  `concatenate` should take a whole list of arrays to join with one call.

Answer (score 1):

very simple, All you have to do is pass it as a function

Comment: Thank you very informative, 

Comment: Pass it *to* the function.

Answer (score 0):

A function taking advantage of list in-place append:

```
In [12]: def foo(alist,n):
    ...:     for n in range(n):
    ...:         alist.append(n)
    ...: 
In [13]: alist=[-2,-1]
In [14]: foo(alist,3)
In [15]: alist
Out[15]: [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
```

but you don't need a function or iteration for that:

```
In [16]: alist=[-2,-1]
In [17]: alist.extend(range(3))
In [18]: alist
Out[18]: [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
```

An array function:

```
In [19]: def foo(arr,n):
    ...:     arr=np.concatenate((arr, np.arange(n)))
    ...:     return arr
    ...: 

In [21]: foo(np.array([-2,-1]),3)
Out[21]: array([-2, -1,  0,  1,  2])
```

This takes the array argument, and returns a new array.  It does not operate in-place.